# How to remove duplicate value in a tab-delimited text file

Tags: text-processing, csv-simple

I have a tab delimited column text like below

```
A      B1      B1     C1
B      B2      D2 
C      C12     C13    C13
D      D3      D5      D9
G      F2      F2
```

how could I convert the above table like below

```
A      B1     C1
B      B2     D2 
C      C12    C13
D      D3     D5     D9
G      F2
```

---

I have extracted my real data file, it is a tab delimited file and I have tried the command line you (Stéphane Chazelas?) posted it works fine but it couldn't remove the duplicate on the last column

```
A  CD274    PDCD1LG2  CD276   PDCD1LG2  CD274
B  NEK2     NEK6      NEK10   NEK10     NEKL-4
C  TNFAIP3  OTUD7B    OTUD7B  TNFAIP3   TNFAIP3
D  DUSP16   DUSP4     DUSP8   VHP-1     DUSP8
E  AGO2     AGO2      AGO2    AGO2      AGO2
```

output need to be as below

```
A  CD274    CD276   PDCD1LG2
B  NEK2     NEK6    NEK10     NEKL-4
C  TNFAIP3  OTUD7B
D  DUSP16   DUSP4   DUSP8     VHP-1
E  AGO2
```

Comment: Does order of fields in a line in output is important ? like `AGO2 E` or `C OTUD7B TNFAIP3`

Comment: @αғsнιη `A` `B` `C` seems to be the line numbering, I think at least they should stay there.

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!" :-)

Answer (score 7):

First set of example data:

```
$ awk -vOFS='\t' '{ r=""; delete t; for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) { if (!t[$i]++) { r = r ? r OFS $i : $i } } print r }' file
A       B1      C1
B       B2      D2
C       C12     C13
D       D3      D5      D9
G       F2
```

Second set of example data (same `awk` script):

```
$ awk -vOFS='\t' '{ r=""; delete t; for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) { if (!t[$i]++) { r = r ? r OFS $i : $i } } print r }' file
A       CD274   PDCD1LG2        CD276
B       NEK2    NEK6    NEK10   NEKL-4
C       TNFAIP3 OTUD7B
D       DUSP16  DUSP4   DUSP8   VHP-1
E       AGO2
```

The script reads the input file `file` line by line, and for each line it goes through each field, building up the output line, `r`.  If the value in a field has already been added to the output line (determined by a lookup table, `t`, of used field values), then the field is ignored, otherwise it's added.

When all the fields of an input line have been processed, the constructed line is outputted.

The output field delimiter is set to tab through `-vOFS='\t'` on the command line.

---

The `awk` script unravelled:

```
{
    r = ""
    delete t

    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
        if (!t[$i]++) {
            r = r ? r OFS $i : $i
        }
    }

    print r
}
```

Comment: See `split("", t)` for the POSIX equivalent to `delete t`

Answer (score 6):

#### sed/tr, uniq and paste

```
while read -r l; do sed 's/\t/\n/g' <<< "$l" | uniq | paste -s; done < test
```

or POSIX compliant:

```
while read -r l; do echo "$l" | tr '\t' '\n' | uniq | paste -s -; done < test
```

For the file `test` this will line by line replace all <kbd>Tab</kbd> characters with linebreaks, run `uniq` to delete dupes and replace the linebreaks with <kbd>Tab</kbd> characters again.

```
$ cat test
A       B1      B1      C1
B       B2      D2
C       C12     C13     C13
D       D3      D5      D9
G       F2      F2

$ while read -r l; do sed 's/\t/\n/g' <<< "$l" | uniq | paste -s; done < test
A       B1      C1
B       B2      D2
C       C12     C13
D       D3      D5      D9
G       F2
```

**NB**: This solution will **not** work for duplicates over multiple rows, e.g. `C1` in

```
A       B1      B1      C1
C1      B       B2      D2
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe something like:

```
gawk -vRS='\\s*\\S*' -vORS= '{$0=RT};$1!=prev;{prev=$1}'
```

The `RS=pattern`...`{$0=RT}` trick lets you process records defined as the parts that match the pattern.

So here, we're slicing the input into `<whitespace><non-whitespace>` `$0` records, `<non-whitespace>` goes in `$1` (the first and only field). We're printing the records whose `$1` is not equal to the previous one.

On an input like:

```
A      B1      B1     C1
B      B2      D2 
C      C12     C13    C13
D      D3      D5      D9
G      F2      F2
```

The records are:

```
[A][      B1][      B1][     C1][
B][      B2][      D2][ 
C][      C12][     C13][    C13][
D][      D3][      D5][      D9][
G][      F2][      F2][
]
```

Doesn't work for your second example though and note that it could remove some newline characters.

Comment: What if a row begins with a dupe from the preceding line, e.g. if we add `C1` at the beginning of row 2? The linebreak clearly should not get removed even then.

Comment: A      CD274   PDCD1LG2        CD276   PDCD1LG2        CD274
B      NEK2    NEK6    NEK10   NEK10   NEKL-4
C      TNFAIP3 OTUD7B  OTUD7B  TNFAIP3 TNFAIP3
D      DUSP16  DUSP4   DUSP8   VHP-1   DUSP8
E      AGO2    AGO2    AGO2    AGO2    AGO2

Comment: @desu, whatever you're trying to say to clarify your question, please edit it in your question. You may want to take the [tour](/tour) for some advise on how to ask great questions.

Comment: @desu add `-F'\n'` to separate each input lines, so `gawk -F'\n' -vRS='\\s*\\S*' -vORS= '{$0=RT};$1!=prev;{prev=$1}'`

Comment: ping to @dessert  too ^^

Comment: @αғsнιη, not sure what you mean.  `\n` is already included in the default FS. The problem here is that if that `\n` is part of a record that is deleted, it will be deleted. Anyway, that answer doesn't answer the OP's question any more with their updated requirements. I'm only leaving it in for the _trick_ which may be useful in other situations.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'm referring to [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394634/how-to-remove-duplicate-value-in-a-tab-delimited-text-file#comment704101_394636). and it since it's removing `\n` within records because when `RS` is defined, so to keeping a line like `C1 CDXWS2  D2` after first line `A      B1      B1     C1`, you need re-enable the `FS` to `\n`

Comment: @αғsнιη, I understand you refer to dessert's comment. But I don't understand how you suggest to address it. To address it, we'd need to preserve the newline in the record being deleted and also remove leading blanks in the next non-deleted record. Too much effort, better to go with a different approach like Kusalananda's

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a code-golf / freak challenge solution:

```
xargs -L1 -I{} echo '; {}' < ./test.txt | \
      xargs -n1 | \
      uniq | \
      xargs | \
      sed -e 's/; /\n/g' -e 's/ \+/\t/g'
```

But it avoids using loops and all other heavy machinery seen in other answers.

*It also builds on an assumption your data doesn't contain `;` character.*

Comment: It also assumes no `"`, `'` backslash characters and that none of the words look like `-n`, `-e`, `-nEne`... (depending on the `echo` implementation) It also assume GNU `sed`. It still spawns one `echo` process per line. But it's true that it's less heavy than some of the `while` loops seen around. It doesn't work for the updated requirements where the duplicated words may no longer be contiguous.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas the argument to `echo` is quoted, so that the values that look like options won't be interpreted as such. What part of `sed` call isn't POSIX? (I honestly don't know).

Comment: No quoting doesn't prevent option processing. Try `printf '%s\n' -n -ne foo | xargs`. Note that `xargs -n1` means that one `echo` is being run for each word which is quite _heavy_ actually. `\n`, `\+` and `\t` are GNU extensions,  though you do find some other implementations supporting it nowadays.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Well, maybe it's `echo` implementation issue, but for me `echo "-n 'foo'" | xargs -L1 -I{} echo '; {}'` prints `; -n foo`, i.e. `-n` wasn't treated as an option. Or, do you mean this will propagate to `uniq`? I think I see your point now.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't apply to the first `echo` as the argument starts with `;`, it applies to the other ones (the ones implictely run by `xargs` upon `xargs` or `xargs -n1` alone).

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`:

unique words on each line:

```
perl -MList::Util=uniq -lape '$_ = join "\t", uniq @F'
```

unique words globally:

```
perl -lape '$_ = join "\t", grep {!$count{$_}++} @F'
```

Or to only consider words of each line starting with the 2<sup>nd</sup> one:

```
perl -lape '$_ = join "\t", shift(@F), grep {!$count{$_}++} @F'
```

Answer (score 0):

With `bash v4.3` (if you don't mind the order of fields as it's sorted except first)

```bsh
while IFS='\n' read -r line; 
    do aline=( $line );
    echo ${aline[0]} $(sort -u <(printf "%s\n" ${aline[@]:1}));
done < infile
```

**Explanation:**

- `aline=( $line )` this make the line save into an array 'aline'
- `${aline[0]}` prints first element of an array 'aline' (array index is starting with zero in `bash`)
- `printf "%s\n" ${aline[@]:1}` prints each element of array 'aline' in separate lines and ignore first element; Then
- `sort -u` sorts each line and remove duplicates entries
- `echo` this also combine splited line elements after sort into one linear.

  Please see below example to have better view of this step:

  ```
  printf "C\n4\nB\nC" |sort -u 
  4
  B
  C
  echo $(printf "C\n4\nB\nC" |sort -u)
  4 B C
  ```

This will give output as:

```
A CD274 CD276 PDCD1LG2
B NEK10 NEK2 NEK6 NEKL-4
C OTUD7B TNFAIP3
D DUSP16 DUSP4 DUSP8 VHP-1
E AGO2
```

Answer (score 0):

### sed substitution with back reference

```sh
sed -re 's/\s+$//; s/(\t[^\t]+)\1+$/\1/'
```

(`s/\s+$//` gets rid of trailing white-space like in your example.)